# Using Django conditional expression while inserting a row

Tags: django-models

I have the following model -

```
class Review(BaseModel,EntityBaseClass):
    review  = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reviewer', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    anonymous_review = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What i want is, if i get a request with anonymous=True, i should not capture the user details but only the review.

I was wondering if this could be achieved using Django conditional expressions.
I have tried-

```
user = request.user
Review.objects.create(review='some review', reviewer=Case(When(Q(params['anonymous_review']),then=user)), 
anonymous_review = Case(When(Q(params['anonymous_review']),then=Value('True')), default=Value('False')))
```

However, the user object is getting converted into string and hence i get error saying reviewer must be a user object instance.
Is there any way around this? 
Is the Django conditional expression not supposed to be used like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people seem to forgot that Django's ORM is just a thin layer above a relational DB, but you obviously got that point - but I'm afraid you're pushing it a but too far indeed ;-)

The expressions you use are wrappers around SQL syntax for complex (select) queries, they are not a replacement for basic Python features:

```
user = request.user

Review.objects.create(
    review='some review', 
    reviewer=user if user.is_authenticated else None, 
    anonymous_review=user.is_anonymous
    )
```